# Spring Batch - "EntityManagerFactory is closed" error when trying to stop Fargate Task after batch job completes

Tags: asynchronous, terraform, spring-batch, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a spring batch application hosted in AWS ECS. I'm trying to configure it so that once the batch job completes, the fargate task also stops. Some points I think are important:

- The task is triggered via an S3 file drop.
- The batch job itself is async
- I'm trying to stop the task in the JobCompletionListener

Here is how I have everything set up:

Batch Config

```
    @Bean
    public JobLauncher asyncJobLauncher()  {
        log.debug("creating async job launcher");
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
        return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job processJob() {
        log.info("launching job...");
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("processJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .start(someStep())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step someStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("someStep").<SomeInput, SomeOutput> chunk(readChunkSize)
                .reader(new SynchronizedItemStreamReaderBuilder<SomeInput>()
                        .delegate(myReader)
                        .build())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .faultTolerant()
                .taskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener listener() { return new JobCompletionListener(); }
    
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<? super SomeInput, ? extends SomeOutput> processor() { return new MyProcessor(); }

    @Bean
    public SomeWriter writer() {
        return new SomeWriter();
    }
```

JobCompletionLister

```
public class JobCompletionListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    private S3Service s3Service;

    private ApplicationContext appCtx;

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            log.debug("BATCH JOB COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY");
        }
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED) {
            log.debug("BATCH JOB FAILED");
        }

        s3Service.deleteFileFromBucket();
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) appCtx).close();

    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.appCtx = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Some relevant terraform config (I have removed the source of the modules):

```
module "task" {
  source    = //some source
  version   = "~> 8.0"
  name      = "manual-letters-td"
  namespace = module.namespace.lower_short_name
  tags      = module.namespace.tags

  task_execution_role  = module.ecs.task_execution_role
  container_definition = [
    module.app_container
  ]
  volumes = [
    {
      name = "certificates"
    }
  ]
}

module "ecs" {
  source      = //some source
  version     = "~> 8.0"
  name                 = "manual-letters"
  namespace            = module.namespace.lower_short_name
  environment          = var.environment
  tags                 = module.namespace.tags
  container_definition = [
    module.app_container
  ]
}

module "ecs_service" {
  source          = //some source
  version         = "~> 8.0"
  name            = "svc"
  namespace       = module.namespace.lower_short_name
  tags            = module.namespace.tags
  vpc_cidr_code   = lookup(var.awsacct_cidr_code, var.environment)
  ecs_cluster     = module.ecs.cluster
  task_definition = module.task.definition
  lb_targets      = module.ecs_alb.lb_targets
  desired_count   = 0
  autoscaling_scale_target_min_capacity = 0
  autoscaling_scale_target_max_capacity = 1
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "events_trust" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole"
    ]
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "events.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}

module "ecs_iam" {
  source    = some source
  version   = "~> 3.0"
  name                = "ecs"
  namespace           = module.namespace.lower_short_name
  tags                = module.namespace.tags
  trust_policy        = data.aws_iam_policy_document.events_trust.json
  policy              = [data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_events_policy_document.json]
  additional_policies = []
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_events_policy_document" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "iam:PassRole"
    ]
    resources = [
      module.ecs.task_execution_role.arn
    ]
  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ecs:RunTask"
    ]
    resources = [
      replace(module.task.definition.arn, "/:\\d+$/", ":*")
    ]
  }
}

module "ecs_target" {
  source      = //some source
  version     = "~> 1.0"
  namespace      = module.namespace.lower_short_name
  name           = "ecs"
  tags           = module.namespace.tags
  environment    = var.environment
  event_bus_name = "default"
  rule_arn       = module.rule.rule.arn
  role_arn       = module.ecs_iam.role.arn
  arn            = module.ecs.cluster.arn
  ecs_target = {
    task_arn      = module.task.definition.arn
    task_count    = 1
    vpc_cidr_code = lookup(var.awsacct_cidr_code, var.environment)
  }
}

module "rule" {
  source      = //some source
  version     = "~> 1.0"
  namespace      = module.namespace.lower_short_name
  name           = "ecs"
  tags           = module.namespace.tags
  environment    = var.environment
  description    = "Triggers from an S3 bucket upload"
  event_bus_name = "default"
  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    source      = ["aws.s3"]
    detail-type = ["Object Created"]
    detail = {
      bucket = {
        name = [module.s3.id]
      }
      object = { key = [{ prefix = "queue/" }] }
    }
  })
}
```

Here is the issue. I am actually able to get the task to stop, However, I am given this error after teh batch job completes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:765)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.proj.myService.MyServiceApplication.main(MyServiceApplication.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:378)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:547)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:158)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManager(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:585)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:487)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:734)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.createNativeEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:485)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:410)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

I'm thinking this has to do with the fact that this job is asynchronous. I am not an expert on this obviously, but I just look at the fact that it's trying to access some datasource (for reading or writing purposes) after the job completes, which it can't do since I've closed the application context. I'm not sure what the best way to shut down the app is. If anybody can provide me with some insight, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use aws batch?  It will automatically start (based off cloudwatch triggers) and stop ecs tasks for you automatically, plus it provides a console out of the box and works really well with spring batch.